# Proverb, quote or phrase which convey that the approach, ideas that are meant to improve the system or process are the onces which fail them

Tags: phrases, idioms, quotes, proverbs

I am looking for a proverb, quote or phrase describing the  processes (or structures or ideas) which are supposed to bring in efficiency, enhance the gaps and increases in-efficiencies, but instead prove to be the reason for the decline of a system.

**Explanation with example**

> Big external agencies were hired in order to define the efficient way to improve the system. However, these agencies do not understand the system and do all sorts of
> trial and error methods to innovate the process for years, yet not only
> do they waste company resources but are paid a ton of money so as to fix what can be done internally.

Comment: Your example is rather an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The road to hell is paved with good intentions? Is 'devil in diguise' too harsh? Neither of those are a great fit. Of course the Germans have a single word for it, but this is the 'English' stack exchange. Here it is in German, if that helps: Verschlimmbesserung.

That which protects, sometimes infects.

Comment: "One of the Yiddish Lears cheekily advertised itself as originally by Shakespeare but now [**verbessert**](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Joel+Berkowitz.+Shakespeare+on+the+American+Yiddish+Stage.-a0120349381) (improved)." Well intentioned? Audacious?

Answer (score 0):

"The cure is worse than the disease" might be what you're looking for.